# join all at once vs creating temp tables

Tags: sql-server, join, temp-tables

I have two queries:

1)

```
select a.*
      ,b.*
      ,c.*
into final_table
from table_a as a
    left join table_b as b
        on a.id_1 = b.id_1
    left join table_c as c
        on a.id_2 = c.id_2;
```

2)

```
select a.*
      ,b.*
into #temp_1
from table_a as a
    left join table_b as b
        on a.id_1 = b.id_1;

select t.*
      ,c.*
into final_table
from #temp_1 as t
    left join table_c as c
        on t.id_2 = c.id_2;
```

I observe that second query runs significantly faster on SQL Server 2012. Is is by accident, or there is a good reason for it?

Comment: Are there any indexes on a, b, c?

Comment: @cloudsafe, good question, let me check, do you think it is going to favor one query over the other?

Comment: @user1700890 I would expect that you do not have indexes because the temp table solution would be slower, not using them. Also, try adding OPTION (RECOMPILE) at the end of each statement so your comparison isn't affected by query plans.

Comment: There are cases where the temp table is better, for example if the estimated row counts are better that way. You should look (and include) query plans and statistics io output for both cases

Comment: The reason may be your statistics are not actual. When SQL Server tries to estimate the result cardinality it uses the statistics, you have only 3 tables but server get the wrong estimation just joining 2 of these. So when you materialized the result of one join, it get the exact cardinality of first join and has chosen the right type of join for the second join